# Django caching in authenticated sites: best practices

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

I need to add memcached to my django website.
It's an authenticated website, where different users see different data on the same pages.
Which are the best practices?
I mean, to avoid users to see each other cached pages (information leak)...

I suppose i should use something like:

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 500 sidebar request.user.username %}
    .. sidebar for logged in user ..
{% endcache %}
```

or:

```
@vary_on_cookie
def my_view(request):
    # ..
```

Which is the safest and better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same thing at all, the [`{% cache %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) allows to cache a template fragment and that's used by the server, `@vary_on_cookie` decorator sets the [Vary response header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers) to Cookie, and that's used by the browser.

Also, you could do `{% cache 500 sidebar request.user %}` instead of specifying the username.

Comment: Yep, it's what is written on doc and what i asked. But what about best practice?

Comment: All I wanted to say is that with @vary_on_cookie nothing is cached on the server, so there is no "safety" issue per-say. With caching by request.user, you bind a cached fragment to a user so there is no "safety" issue per-say.